# Django Rest Framework - call serializer.to_internal_value on a null value

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I am attempting to write a Field Serializer for my django API that passes `null` to a custom `.to_internal_value` method.

My use case is for two `datetime` fields that make up a time range. I want a user of my API to be able to give me something along the lines of `"start_dt": null` in a PUT/POST/PATCH request and have my serializer translate that into `datetime.datetime.min` (or, in the case of `end_dt`, `datetime.datetime.max`).

Here is what I have so far. I am able to get `Object->JSON` serialization to work well (translates `datetime.min` and `datetime.max` values to `None`) using the `.to_representation(self, value)` method - however it does not seem to call `.to_internal_value(self, value)` when converting from `null->None` - and instead passes `None` through to the rest of my logic whenever one of the two fields is given as `null`.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

UTC = pytz.timezone("UTC")
max_dt = UTC.localize(datetime.max)
min_dt = UTC.localize(datetime.min)

class CustomDateTimeField(serializers.Field):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.datetime_field = fields.DateTimeField()

        self.infinity_direction = kwargs.pop('infinity_direction', None)
        if not (self.infinity_direction == '+' or self.infinity_direction == '-'):
            raise AssertionError("Expected CustomDateTimeField to be created with `infinity_direction` equal to either '+' or '-'")

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Represent both MAX and MIN times as None/'null'
        Else return a normal datetime string
        """

        if value == min_dt or value == max_dt:
            return None

        return self.datetime_field.to_representation(value)


    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        """
        Translate None/'null' values to either MAX or MIN - depending on self.infinity_direction
        Else return a normal datetime object
        """

        if value == None:
            return max_dt if self.infinity_direction == '+' else min_dt

        return self.datetime_field.to_internal_value(value)
```

In my Model's serializer I have these fields in use like...

```
class TimeRangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    start_dt = CustomDateTimeField(infinity_direction='-', allow_null=True)
    end_dt = CustomDateTimeField(infinity_direction='+', allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TimeRange
        fields = ('id', 'start_dt', 'end_dt')
```

To provide some more examples...

**EX 1:**
Posting this

```
{}
```

gives the following correct return value

```
{
    "end_dt": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "start_dt": [
        "This field is required."
    ]

}
```

**EX 2:**

Posting this

```
{
    "start_dt": null,
    "end_dt": null
}
```

`CustomDateTimeField.to_internal_value` never gets called - and `start_dt` and `end_dt` get passed to my object's creation as `None`, instead of the desired `datetime.min` and `datetime.max` values.

**EX 3:**

Posting this

```
{
    "start_dt": "2018-08-28T00:00:00Z",
    "end_dt": null
}
```

Seems to call `to_internal_value` - but only for `start_dt` (which it resolves correctly into a datetime object). It does not call `to_internal_value` on the `null`.

Comment: Where are `min_dt` and `max_dt` defined?

Comment: Sorry - knew I forgot some snippet. I updated the first code snippet in my code to include them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code as below:

```
def to_internal_value(self, value):
    """
    Translate None/'null' values to either MAX or MIN - depending on self.infinity_direction
    Else return a normal datetime object
    """

    return self.datetime_field.to_internal_value(value)

def validate_empty_values(self, data):
    (is_empty_value, data) = super(CustomDateTimeField, self).validate_empty_values(data)

    if is_empty_value and data is None:
        return is_empty_value, max_dt if self.infinity_direction == '+' else min_dt

    return is_empty_value, data
```

drf never calls the `to_interval_value` of a field if its value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the framework don't bother in trying to de-serialize a field that is 'null' in the JSON, since no matter what Field type you're dealing with, 'null' will always be de-serialize to None.

You have a very special use case, but hey, you're lucky, you're the one writing the API. Just tell the user/s of your API that has to use some placeholder for that, for instance: `min_date_limit` or `max_date_limit`.

If you detect one of those values in the `to_internal_value` function, well, you know what to do.

Comment: From what I can tell my code is never even calling my custom `to_internal_value` function - it seems on `null` values it skips it and ALWAYS passes through `None`

Comment: Have you try a breakpoint?  I think it does, but  I think `return self.datetime_field.to_internal_value(value)`  returns *None* if `value` is 'null'

Comment: Justed tested again, with some breakpoints. Does not go into the function - and my `TimeRangeSerializer.validate(self, data)` method gets called with `{"start_dt": None, "end_dt": None}`. I guess I could always intercept these values at that point...

Comment: I just see your problem, the last line in your custom field class is not correctly indented!! Is outside the function, that's why you get None as result.

Comment: Unfortunately, that err was in the copy/paste only :/ Thanks for your continued effort :D

Comment: If the function is not called, you are asking the wrong question  :).  And showing the wrong code also. You need to show the code where you assume produces the function call.

Comment: I was thinking that, when reading a JSON object which was given to the TimeRangeSerializer, it would use `to_internal_value` to resolve the raw JSON value into what it would actually use. It actually does use that function, if I give `start_dt` or `end_dt` a string such as `"2018-08-28T00:00:00Z"`, just not if they are `null` ----- I added another example in my original question with that info

Comment: I see, so it seems the framework don't bother in trying to de-serialize a field that is 'null' in the JSON, since no matter what Field type you're dealing with, null will always be de-serialize to `None`.  You have a very special use case, but hey, you're lucky, you're the one writing the API. Just tell the user for your API that has to use some placeholder for that, for instance: 'min_date_limit' or 'max_date_limit'. If you detect one of those values in the `to_internal_value` function, well, you know what to do.